# Testing a private prototype method in JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, prototype, private

I was wondering if it was possible to test a private method of a prototype in js. I suspect it's impossible but maybe someone would surprise me...

For example, suppose I have the following class restaurant:

```
function Restaurant() {
}

Restaurant.prototype = (function() {
    var private_stuff = function() {
    // Private code here
    };

    return {

        constructor:Restaurant,

        use_restroom:function() {
            private_stuff();
        }

    };
})();
```

Would it be possible to write a unit test for private_stuff method? I use jasmine for my unit tests, but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Typically unit testing only applies to public methods. As long as `use_restroom` is correct in all cases who cares how `private_stuff` works?

Comment: I would have to disagree on that. A public method that uses other private methods may be very hard to cover entirely with unit tests. Sometimes you want to cover the private methods. That's why we have frameworks like powermock for java unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I faced something similar, I had to specifically expose private stuff, as odd as that sounds:

```
function Restaurant() {
}

Restaurant.prototype = (function() {
    var private_stuff = function() {
    // Private code here
    };

    var internalMethods = {};
    if (window.exposeInteralMethods) {
      internalMethods = {
        private_stuff: private_stuff
      };
    }

    return {   
        internalMethods: internalMethods,
        constructor:Restaurant,    
        use_restroom:function() {
            private_stuff();
        }

    };
})();
```

You are at risk if anyone sets `window.exposeInteralMethods` besides you, but sometimes one needs 2x4 debugging of the squirmware.